# Problems with Spring Forms and Validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am newer to Spring, previously I've worked in PHP and Python. I am having some issues understanding how Spring forms work and are validated. My understanding thus far is that when you are using the  your form is backed by a bean, meaning you must provide a bean to the JSP. You can also use the stand HTML forms but then you have to manually retrieve the request parameters in the controller.

Here is the issue I am having. I have a User bean that is using Hibernate Validator, and I have add, edit pages for users. The issue is I don't want the password field to appear on the Edit page, the password is going to be garbage anyway because its using BCrypt. However when the form is submitted validation fails because it expects the password to be present. There doesn't seem to be anyway to do partial bean implementation using Spring Form.

I would like to use Spring Form if possible because it reduces repetitive validation code, and its always nice to work with objects. My thoughts now are do I create an intermediate object and then translate the data from that to my bean. Seems tedious and can lead to the creation of way to many objects. My other thought is to just using plain old HTML forms and pull the params myself and set the values in the object.

I'm not sure what is the best approach or if I'm even thinking on the right track. Spring Forms and the validation is offers seems great, but seems like it isn't particularly flexible. Like I said I'm new to Spring so I may just be missing something or not understanding.

Another issue I have been wrestling with is having multiple objects needed on a form. Lets say I have a User bean, which has the following Properties.

private Role role;
private Country country;

So I need to pass User, List, and List to my JSP. I can get them to display fine, however if the form validation fails when it returns to that page, I lose my role and country objects, unless I re-add them to the model before returning the view name. Am I missing something here or is that the norm. It's a request object so I guess that makes sense but seems tedious to have to re-add them every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding thus far is that when you are using the your form is
>   backed by a bean, meaning you must provide a bean to the JSP.

I'd say mostly true.  The form is backed by a bean, but the Spring JSTL tags know how to get to the bean based on the set modelAttribute.  The bean is living in what you would consider "page" scope, unless you add set your model attribute to be in session.  Either way, if you are using the Spring JSTL tags, they are going to one or the other place to get it.

> You can also use the stand HTML forms but then you have to manually
>   retrieve the request parameters in the controller.

Not true.  You can "simulate" the same thing that the Spring JSTL tags are doing.  Understand that JSTL tags are very much like macros.  They are simply copying in some pre-determined block of code into the output with some very rudimentary conditional statements.  The key bit that Spring MVC needs to wire the Model Attribute on the Controller side is the `name` and `value`, which are easy to decipher how those get generated/wired together.

> However when the form is submitted validation fails because it expects
>   the password to be present.

You could create a "DTO" or "Data Transmission Object", which is basically a go-between to take the values from the UI and are converted in the Controller/Service layer to the real Model objects on the backend.  Or, if you are lazy like me, put the User in session scope, in which case you don't have to post the value as Spring will take the one out of session and just updated the one or two fields you did post.  Don't post the password, Spring wont set the password.

> My thoughts now are do I create an intermediate object and then
>   translate the data from that to my bean.

Yes, this is the DTO I referred to.  You only need to do it where you need to.

> I'm not sure what is the best approach or if I'm even thinking on the
>   right track.

There are probably thousands of ways to do anything in coding, some more right or wrong than others.  I know some developers who are design-Nazi's and would say you should always do it one way or another, but I am not one of those people.  I think as long as you are consistent, and you are not doing something completely boneheaded you are on the right track.  My #1 concern with all the code I write is maintainability.  I

1. Don't want to spend 20hrs trying to re-learn what I did 6mo ago, so I tend to choose the simpler option
2. Hate repeating code, so I tend to choose more module designs
3. Hate having to spend 20hrs trying to re-learn what I did 6mo ago, so tend to make heavy use of JavaDoc and comments where I find the code is tricky (lots of loops, doing something weird, etc)

> Another issue I have been wrestling with is having multiple objects
>   needed on a form.

There are several ways to deal with this too.  I have never used it, but you CAN actually have more than one Model Attribute associated with the same form and Controller handler.  I think you use a `<spring:bind>` tag or something.  I have seen samples around, so Google it if you think you need that.

My approach is usually to either put something in session or build a DTO to hold all the things I need.  The first I use more for things like lists to drive building the view, for instance if I have a drop down of States coming from a table.  I would have a List of the States put into session and just use them from there, that way I only go after them once and done.

I use the DTO approach (some might call it a Form Bean) when I have a complex gaggle of things I need to change all at once, but the things are not necessarily connected directly.  Just to point out: You can have nested objects in your model attributes and use them in your Spring JSTL tags.  You can also have Collections (List, Set, Map) in your Model Attribute and get to those as well, although Spring doesn't handle nested Collections very well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, great answer, thanks for the explanation. This helps point me in the right direction. I'll look into the DTO concept. Thanks again for taking the time to put together a well explained answer!